# Cannot completely restore root in MYSQL – cannot GRANT ALL

Tags: mysql

Somehow I lost root in mysql and I am trying to recover it.

I inserted root into the user table using the  --skip-grant-tables option and then I ran

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
```

Then I started mysql regularly without --skip-grant-tables option
That’s what I see:

```
/usr/java/ep622_svn => mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.6.17 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: I'll bet anything you can find similar questions on dba.SE.

Comment: If you mean http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html this did not help - I tried

Comment: I mean http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+root+permissions

Answer (score -1):

This link helped:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97439/how-do-i-give-rootlocalhost-permission-to-grant-privileges-in-mysql

One needs to execute under running with --skip-grant-tables option:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET
Select_priv='Y',Insert_priv='Y',Update_priv='Y',Delete_priv='Y',
Create_priv='Y',Drop_priv='Y',Reload_priv='Y',Shutdown_priv='Y',
Process_priv='Y',File_priv='Y',Grant_priv='Y',References_priv='Y',
Index_priv='Y',Alter_priv='Y',Show_db_priv='Y',Super_priv='Y',
Create_tmp_table_priv='Y',Lock_tables_priv='Y',Execute_priv='Y',
Repl_slave_priv='Y',Repl_client_priv='Y',Create_view_priv='Y',
Show_view_priv='Y',Create_routine_priv='Y',Alter_routine_priv='Y',
Create_user_priv='Y',Event_priv='Y',Trigger_priv='Y',
Create_tablespace_priv='Y'
WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Obviously this will fail too, with `permission denied` error.

Comment: This is under running  with --skip-grant-tables option, I corrected the answer